# crontab command - execute and than email log file (with 2 options)

Tags: php, email, cron, cron-task

I need to run my php code each hour, and my knowledge about crontab/cronjob is pretty bad.
I want the script to run each hour and send email for 2 case: success and failure.
I wrote this code but I don't know if it's good for crontab (I think it's not working):

```
0 * * * * php <full-path-script>
if [ “$?” = “0” ]; then
echo “Backup Process was Successful. A new log file <filename>.txt has been
created” | mail -s “Backup Status Successful” <email> -A <path>
<filename>.txt
else
echo “Backup Process Failed. Please contact System Administrator.  A new log
file <filename>.txt has been created” | mail -s “Backup Status Failed” 
<email> -A <path><filename>.txt
```

if you think I should do it different please explain and show me how.
BTW - I'm working with postfix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is what I've done to solve my problem:

First - Be sure to write all your shell scripts on Linux (otherwise you script will get messed up and you won't even be able to see it), you can setup your own Linux using vmware or other program.

This is my shell script:

```
`#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php <full-path-script>

if [ “$?” = “0” ]
then

echo “Backup Process was Successful. A new log file `date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d-
\%H"`.txt has been created” | mail -s “Backup Status Successful” <email-
address> -a <path>`date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H"`.txt

else

echo “Backup Process Failed. Please contact System Administrator” | mail -s
“Backup Status Failed” <email-address> -a <path>`date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H"`.txt

fi`
```

In order to make sure your script will send error into $? you should avoid using die(); on errors, In fact you should use exit(1); (it'll put 1 in $? so we'll know the script failed to run).

Don't forget to make cronjob that will task this script for you and send you notifications to your email address :)

I hope this help anyone!

Answer (score 0):

OK, You can solve your issue with writing / running two PHP scripts together.

1. Existing script, just add writing to file, write it in CSV format the start time and the end time of the script. [ Each run in new line ]
2. Run another "deamon" PHP script every x minutes via crontab that parse the CSV file, the script goals are: Parsing the CSV file and searching for lines with start time and without end time, and sending an email if something wrong in CSV file.

Pay attention,last line in CSV file can be active process, so take interval or time time that you think its should done.

```
//Create another PHP file / class that sends an email and control it from the php code.

// the message
$msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

// send email
mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
```

What can interrupt in PHP in your code ? use timeouts / try catch / reties mechanism to reduce the failures.

Comment: I thought about doing it, but is it possible to do it with crontab? because I'll need to add a lot of try catch in order to make sure my script send email with log.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I'm really interested to do it via cronjob. I tried to create shell script file that run my php and send email for result each hour.. but somehow the shell couldn't find the php interpreter

Comment: This is why you should log it to file.